# Make a php exec to run in a parallel process on CLI

Tags: php, linux, exec, command-line-interface

Im running this php file from a linux host, and I have this line of code:

```
exec('sleep 60 && wget http://thisismyurlpath?id='.''.$insert_id);
```

This will trigger on a if statement, and the URL function call takes some time to execute it, and there is the sleep part.

I want to run that exec on a different process (thread) so that I won't be affected on the slow run time of that process and my after if statements in my script to run independent of that slow exec.

Comment: I hope you're validating $insert_id thoroughly because you might be in for some nasty surprises if you're not. :)  As for running something in the background you can use the shell background job facilities if the job is something you can just "fire and forget (ie you don't need the output in the script that initiates the job)"

Comment: The output of the wget is saved on my function called side.

Comment: Then you have to wait for the output, or at least write a script that starts the job, waits for the output and processes it that you can launch from another PHP script.  PHP is not threaded and doesn't have events (unless you use non-standard extensions like pthreads) so there's no way of getting a single PHP script to start another job and return to process the output.

Comment: Hmm I read that there is a & that I can use for this, I will try to put that to the final of the exec.

Comment: You can use &, but then you can't wait for the output.  That's why I said you could background the job provided it's "fire and forget" and you don't need it's output in the script that starts it.

Comment: @TatuBogdan http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php